# Node js, promessas, callback

Tags: node.js, callback, promises

Preciso que seja executada determinados updates e delete dentro de um retorno de um consulta no meu controller. porém é executado apenas a ultima função 
acredito que não estou entendo como se usa promessas.

```
 api.adMaster =  function (req, res) {
        var dados = req.body;
        var ultimo = false;
        var addados = {ad:'', emp:''}
        var time = new Date();
        var promessas = [];
        var resutados = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < dados.length ; i++) {
            if(dados[i].aut.length>2){
                var metade = Math.floor(dados[i].aut.length / 2);
                var resultado = "'"+dados[i].aut.substr(0,metade)+"','"+dados[i].aut.substr(metade)+"'";
                dados[i].aut = resultado
                dados[i].data = convertData(time);
                dados[i].hora = converHora(time);
            }
            addados.ad += ","+dados[i].ad
            addados.emp += ","+dados[i].emp
        }
        addados.ad =  addados.ad.substring(1);
        addados.emp =  addados.emp.substring(1);
        var promessas = [];
        solicitacaoSqlDAO.adMaster(addados, function (erro, recordset) {
            if (erro) {
                console.log("#$# Erro ao adMaster #$#");
                console.log(erro);
            } else {
                var compAD = '';
                var ad;
                console.log( recordset.recordset.length);
                recordset.recordset.forEach(function(data, index) {
                    ad = data;
                    if(compAD==data.NUM_AD){
                        ultimo = true;
                    }
                    if( recordset.recordset.length ==  1){
                        ultimo = true;
                    }
                    if(ultimo || !dados[0].condicao){ 
                        promessas.push(new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
                            solicitacaoSqlDAO.updateiesSupCapS(ad).then(result=>{
                                resutados.push(result);
                                console.log('updateiesSupCapS');
                                resolver();
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO updateiesSupCapS  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO updateiesSupCapS  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                            });
                        }));
                        promessas.push(new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
                            solicitacaoSqlDAO.updateiesSupCapC(ad).then(result=>{
                                resutados.push(result);
                                console.log('updateiesSupCapC');
                                resolver();
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  updateiesSupCapC ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  updateiesSupCapC ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                            });
                        }));
                        promessas.push(new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
                            solicitacaoSqlDAO.updateIesLibPgtoCapN(ad).then(result=>{
                                resutados.push(result);
                                console.log('updateIesLibPgtoCapN');
                                resolver();
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  updateIesLibPgtoCapN  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  updateIesLibPgtoCapN  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                            });
                        }));
                        promessas.push(new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
                            solicitacaoSqlDAO.deleteCapAdSuspAprov(ad).then(result=>{
                                resutados.push(result);
                                console.log('deleteCapAdSuspAprov');
                                resolver();
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  deleteCapAdSuspAprov  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(" @###$$$$##$  ERRO  deleteCapAdSuspAprov  ###$$$#$#$#$$#");
                            }); 
                        }));
                        ultimo = false;
                        compAD=data.NUM_AD; 


                    }else{
                        res.status(200).json({resutado:'aguardando outro aprovador'});;
                    }
                });
                Promise.all([true, promessas]).then(function(values) {
                    console.log(values);
                    res.status(200).json(resutados);
                }).catch(function() {
                    res.status(404).json("erro");
                });
            }
        })
    };
```

No meu debug no console.log(values)
vem esse resultado

```
[ true,
  [ Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> } ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás a fazer bem com as Promises mas não com o `Promise.all`, esse método aceita uma array de promises. O que lhe estás a dar é uma array com um booleano e uma array.

Usa assim:

```
Promise.all(promessas).then(... etc...
```

---

Repara também que no final, dentro de `Promise.all` tens

```
res.status(200).json(resutados);
```

e acho que queres `values`:

```
res.status(200).json(values);
```

Comment: Sergio, so pra deixa o feedback, tive que realizar as consulta de outra forma, acredito que foi alguma coisa haver sobre o jeito que implementei o meu DAO, vou ter que parar uma hora  para ver isso com mais calma.
desde de ja obrigado ai pela força.. aprendi de fato maneiras de implementar promessas e mapeamento haha vlw

Comment: @CiroStodulskideAzevedo oi! Estou fora de casa esta semana, por isso vou estar pouco por aqui. Dou uma olhada depois de novo!